# Firebase Custom Userfield crash - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase

As the title said. I want to make a custom authentication with username on Register form. All code was good and there is no error. But when I'm trying to run the app, It's force close when After I click the Registration button from the Login page. So this is the list code in SignUp.java

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

//Variabel
private EditText regName, regNpm, regUsername, regEmail, regPassword, regCoPassword;
private Button regBtn, regToLoginBtn;
ProgressBar signUp_progress;

private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

String fullname, username, email, npm, password, co_password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Line dibawah untuk menghilangkan status bar dari screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    //Hooks ke semua elemen xml di activity_sign_up.xml
    signUp_progress = findViewById(R.id.signUp_progress);
    regName = findViewById(R.id.reg_name);
    regNpm = findViewById(R.id.reg_npm);
    regUsername = findViewById(R.id.reg_username);
    regEmail = findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
    regPassword = findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
    regCoPassword = findViewById(R.id.reg_CoPassword);
    regBtn = findViewById(R.id.reg_btn);
    regToLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.reg_login_btn);

    //        Get Firebase auth instance
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("UserData");

    regToLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //        handle user SignUp button
    regBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!validateFullname() | !validateUsername() | !validateEmail() | !validatePassword() | !validateNpm()) {
                return;
            }

            if (regPassword.equals(regCoPassword)) {

                //    progressbar VISIBLE
                signUp_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, String.valueOf(regPassword)).addOnCompleteListener
                        (new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    UserData data = new UserData(fullname, username, email, npm);

                                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UserData")
                                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(data).
                                            addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                                    //    progressbar GONE
                                                    signUp_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Successful Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, MenuActivity.class);
                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                    finish();
                                                }
                                            });


                                } else {
                                    //    progressbar GONE
                                    signUp_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Check Email id or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Password didn't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });


}

private boolean validateFullname() {
    fullname = regName.getText().toString().trim();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fullname)) {
        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Enter Your Full Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean validateUsername() {
    username = regUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Enter Your User Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
private boolean validateNpm() {
    npm = regNpm.getText().toString().trim();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(npm)) {
        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Enter Your NPM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean validateEmail() {
    email = regEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Enter Your Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please enter valid Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean validatePassword() {
    password  = regPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    co_password = regCoPassword.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Enter Your Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(co_password)) {
        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Enter Your Co-Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else if (password.length() <= 6) {
        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Password is Very Short", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

//    if the user already logged in then it will automatically send on Dashboard/MainActivity activity.
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }


}
```

}

And this is the  listing code from Login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
//Variabel
Button callSignUp, loginBtn;
ImageView image;
TextView logoText, sloganText;
TextInputLayout username, password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Line dibawah untuk menghilangkan status bar dari screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //Hooks
    callSignUp = findViewById(R.id.signup_screen);
    image = findViewById(R.id.logo_image);
    logoText = findViewById(R.id.logo_text);
    sloganText = findViewById(R.id.slogan_text);
    username = findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);
    loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);



    callSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,SignUp.class);

            Pair[] pairs = new Pair[7];

            pairs [0] = new Pair<View,String>(image,"logo_image");
            pairs [1] = new Pair<View,String>(logoText,"logo_text");
            pairs [2] = new Pair<View,String>(sloganText,"logo_desc");
            pairs [3] = new Pair<View,String>(username,"uname_tran");
            pairs [4] = new Pair<View,String>(password,"password_tran");
            pairs [5] = new Pair<View,String>(loginBtn,"button_tran");
            pairs [6] = new Pair<View,String>(callSignUp,"login_signup_tran");

            ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(Login.this,pairs);
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());

        }
    });

}
```

}

And then there's  logcat

```
2020-10-13 00:24:08.213 5297-5336/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x77c26384a380: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x77c2f32f8280)
2020-10-13 00:24:08.225 5297-5336/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x77c26384a380: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x77c2f32f8280)
2020-10-13 00:24:08.230 5297-5336/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp E/BufferQueueProducer: [unnamed-5297-8] setMaxDequeuedBufferCount: 2 dequeued buffers would exceed the maxBufferCount (2) (maxAcquired 1 async 0 mDequeuedBufferCannotBlock 0)
2020-10-13 00:24:08.230 5297-5336/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp E/Surface: IGraphicBufferProducer::setBufferCount(3) returned Invalid argument
2020-10-13 00:24:08.231 5297-5336/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x77c26384a380: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x77c2f32f8280)
2020-10-13 00:24:08.240 5297-5336/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x77c26384a380: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x77c2f32f8280)
2020-10-13 00:24:08.244 5297-5336/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x77c26384a380: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x77c2f32f8280)
2020-10-13 00:24:08.251 5297-5297/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@5690764
2020-10-13 00:24:08.257 5297-5333/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-10-13 00:24:08.259 5297-5339/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 12594
2020-10-13 00:24:08.261 5297-5339/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-10-13 00:24:08.267 5297-5339/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp V/FA: Activity paused, time: 130626
2020-10-13 00:24:08.288 5297-5297/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
2020-10-13 00:24:08.312 5297-5297/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp I/chatty: uid=10134(com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp) identical 4 lines
2020-10-13 00:24:08.320 5297-5297/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
2020-10-13 00:24:08.332 5297-5339/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-10-13 00:24:08.576 5297-5297/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-10-13 00:24:09.200 5297-5297/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp, PID: 5297
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp.SignUp}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
        at com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp.SignUp.onCreate(SignUp.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
2020-10-13 00:24:10.531 5297-5297/com.hardy.gunadarmastudentapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5297 SIG: 9
```

Then the activity_sign_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SignUp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#8f4dc9"
    android:padding="20dp">



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:transitionName="logo_image"
        android:src="@drawable/logogundar"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logo_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/acme"
        android:text="Menu Register"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:transitionName="logo_text"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slogan_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Isi NPM, username, dan email untuk sign in"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reg_name"
            android:hint="Nama"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reg_npm"
            android:hint="NPM"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reg_username"
            android:hint="Username"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="15"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reg_email"
            android:hint="Email"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reg_password"
            android:hint="Password"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            android:transitionName="password_tran"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/reg_CoPassword"
            android:hint="Confirm Password"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            android:transitionName="coPassword_tran"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reg_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Register"
            android:background="#000"
            android:textColor="#FFF"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/reg_login_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Udah ada akun? Sign in sini"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:textColor="#FFF"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/signUp_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Nah, there's the code sir....

Answer (score 1):

it says ClassCastException because you treat TextInputLayout as EditText. Set a separate id for for the wrapped editText and call getText() on that view instead.

Comment: Thanks, its work. But there's another problem, when I'm try to register. I already type the same password and confirm password. But it said the password didn't match

Comment: This is for the password didn't match
https://ibb.co/0Fw9XK6

Comment: alright, but that is another question with your matching logic.

Comment: Should I make a new question mate?

Comment: the description does not match your problem. So that would probably be a good idea. If I were you I would debug one time and see why it does not match. @Hardy

Comment: @Hardy isn't this the correct answer? You seems to have other problem as well, but the answer looks ok for this question.

Comment: Yes it's already fixed mate @DanielLarsson. Do I need to make a new quest for a new problem?